# what's the difference between a role and a task list and when to use?

Tags: ansible

In ansible, there are **include_role** and **include_tasks** modules
what's the difference between them? when to use which of them?

I have a role running on a windows host that requires the variables generated from a linux host. which one should I use in order to run a role in a different host?

Answer (score 2):

Include_role: Includes the full role, not only a task file, for example include roles will include: vars, meta, handlers...

Include_tasks: you can call a simple playbook.yml with tasks inside, just a file dont need to be a full role.

Comment: Somre more and background information can be found under [What's the difference between include_tasks and import_tasks?](https://serverfault.com/a/875292/448950).